# Textos relacionado as "Medalhas" não estão traduzido na versão mobile do perfil

Tags: bug, status-aceito, tradução, internacionalização

Olhe o *screenshot* de um usuário aleatório (que foi retirado do perfil no modo *mobile*). Supostamente deveria estar escrito em português mas está em inglês.

[image]

Meu [post anterior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303916/350567) foi fechado no MSE. E os usuários me direcionaram para esse site específico do SOpt.

---

### English Version

**Title:** Text related to badges are not translated in the mobile version of users' profiles

Look at the screenshot of a random user from the mobile version of the site. Supposedly, it should be in Portuguese, but it's in English:

[image]

My [previous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303916/350567) was closed on MSE. The users sent me to this specific Meta for SOpt.

Comment: Obrigado, @rray

Comment: Thank u. I've already submitted the translations into [our Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/).

Comment: Está realmente em inglês mesmo, basta alterar para a versão movel no pc para ver: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPRg6.jpg

Comment: Não, não. Isso é uma mensagem secreta. Badges é o barzinho onde a diretoria se encontra pra tomar uma dourada de vez em quando.